# Auto reloading Flask app when source code changes

Tags: python, flask, foreman

I know for a fact that Flask, in debug mode, will detect changes to .py source code files and will reload them when new requests come in.

I used to see this in my app all the time.  Change a little text in an @app.route decoration section in my views.py file, and I could see the changes in the browser upon refresh.

But all of a sudden (can't remember what changed), this doesn't seem to work anymore.

Q: Where am I going wrong?

I am running on a OSX 10.9 system with a VENV setup using Python 2.7.  I use `foreman start` in my project root to start it up.

App structure is like this:

```
[Project Root]
+-[app]
| +-__init__.py
| +- views.py
| +- ...some other files...
+-[venv]
+- config.py
+- Procfile
+- run.py
```

The files look like this:

```
# Procfile
web: gunicorn --log-level=DEBUG run:app
```

```py
# config.py
contains some app specific configuration information.
```

```py
# run.py
from app import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True, port = 5000)
```

```py
# __init__.py
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.login import LoginManager
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask.ext.mail import Mail
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

#mail sending
mail = Mail(app)

lm = LoginManager()
lm.init_app(app)
lm.session_protection = "strong"

from app import views, models
```

```py
# app/views.py
@app.route('/start-scep')
def start_scep():
    startMessage = '''\
<html>
<header>
<style>
body { margin:40px 40px;font-family:Helvetica;}
h1 { font-size:40px; }
p { font-size:30px; }
a { text-decoration:none; }
</style>
</header>

<p>Some text</p>
</body>
</html>\
'''
    response = make_response(startMessage)
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = "text/html"
    print response.headers
    return response
```

Comment: My guess is you started using `foreman run` instead of `python run.py` - Flask isn't in control when you run it under gunicorn and so it can't do the auto-reloading.

Comment: @SeanVieira I use `foreman start` from command line.  Should I do `foreman run python run.py`?

Comment: Yes, that is what you would want to do (most likely) - if that doesn't work, use `python run.py` instead.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The issue here, as stated in other answers, is that it looks like you moved from `python run.py` to `foreman start`, or you changed your `Procfile` from

```
# Procfile
web: python run.py
```

to

```
# Procfile
web: gunicorn --log-level=DEBUG run:app
```

When you run `foreman start`, it simply runs the commands that you've specified in the `Procfile`. (I'm going to guess you're working with Heroku, but even if not, this is nice because it will mimic what's going to run on your server/Heroku dyno/whatever.)

So now, when you run `gunicorn --log-level=DEBUG run:app` (via `foreman start`) you are now running your application with `gunicorn` rather than the built in webserver that comes with `Flask`. The `run:app` argument tells `gunicorn` to look in `run.py` for a `Flask` instance named `app`, import it, and run it. This is where it get's fun: since the `run.py` is being imported, `__name__ == '__main__'` is `False` (see more on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)), and so `app.run(debug = True, port = 5000)` is never called.

This is what you want (at least in a setting that's available publicly) because the webserver that's built into `Flask` that's used when `app.run()` is called has some pretty serious security vulnerabilities. The `--log-level=DEBUG` may also be a bit deceiving since it uses the word "DEBUG" but it's only telling `gunicorn` which logging statements to print and which to ignore (check out the [Python docs on logging](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html).)

The solution is to run `python run.py` when running the app locally and working/debugging on it, and only run `foreman start` when you want to mimic a production environment. Also, since `gunicorn` only needs to import the `app` object, you could remove some ambiguity and change your `Procfile` to

```
# Procfile
web: gunicorn --log-level=DEBUG app:app
```

You could also look into [Flask Script](http://flask-script.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) which has a built in command `python manage.py runserver` that runs the built in Flask webserver in debug mode.

Answer (score 6):

The solution was to stop using `foreman start` as stated in the comments and directly execute `python run.py`.

This way, the `app.run` method with the `debug=True` and `use_reloader=True` configuration parameters take effect.

Answer (score 5):

Sample Application where **app** is our application and this application had been saved in the file **start.py**:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hallo():
    return 'Hello World, this is really cool... that rocks... LOL'
```

now we start the application from the shell with the flag **--reload**

```
gunicorn -w 1 -b 127.0.0.1:3032 start:app --reload
```

and gunicorn reloads the application at the moment the file has changed automaticly. No need to change anything at all.

if you'd love to run this application in the background add the flag **-D**

```
gunicorn -D -w 1 -b 127.0.0.1:3032 start:app --reload
```

> -D Demon mode
>
> -w number of workers
>
> -b address and port
>
> start (start.py) :app - application
>
> --reload gunicorns file monitoring

Look at the settings file:
http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/settings.html

all options and flags are mentioned there. Have fun!

Comment: just note that --reload is incompatible with the preload option
https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/settings.html#reload